# How to delete object in array?

Tags: json, reactjs, redux

I used componentDidUpdate and in it I put a shift method, which is used to delete an object from a JSON array and thereby re-render the displayed posts, but the shift method deletes the first object from the array independently in which the delete button on the post will I press? Is there any possibility, then, to bypass the deletion of the first element in favor of the one that is designated to be deleted?

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const {posts} = this.props;
        const indexPosts = posts.findIndex((post) => post.id === this.state.postId);

        if(prevProps.posts !== posts){
            this.handleData();
        } else if (indexPosts !== -1)
        {
            this.informationAlert();
            const log = posts.splice(indexPosts, 1);
            console.log(log);
        }   
    }
```

EDIT: Actions

```
export const deletedPost = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    axios
        .delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, id, {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((post) =>
            dispatch({
                type: DELETED_POST,
                payload: post.data
            })
        )
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

```
import { FETCH_POSTS, NEW_POST, DELETED_POST, FETCH_COMMENTS, NEW_COMMENT } from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
    items: [],
    item: {},
    itemComent: [],
    itemNewComment: {},
    deletedPost: []
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_POSTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: action.payload
            };
        case NEW_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                item: action.payload
            };
        case DELETED_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                deletedPost: action.payload
            };
        case FETCH_COMMENTS:
            return {
                ...state,
                itemComent: action.payload
            }
        case NEW_COMMENT:
            return {
                ...state,
                itemNewComment: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    posts: state.posts.items,
    newPost: state.posts.item,
    deletedPost2: state.posts.deletedPost
});
```

EDIT 3:

```
handleDeletedPost = (id) => {
        this.setState({
            postId: id
        })
    }
```

Edit 4:

```
//I added in constructor 
this.state: dataPost: '',

//next I create function to load data and send to state dataPost
handleData = (e) => {
        const {posts} = this.props;
        const {dataPost} = this.state;
        const letang = posts;
        const postsData = dataPost;

        if (postsData.length <= 0) {            
            this.setState({
                dataPost: letang
            })
        } else {
            console.log('stop')
        }       
    }
// next i create in componentDidUpdate this code
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const {posts} = this.props;
        const indexPosts = posts.findIndex((post) => post.id === this.state.postId);

        if(prevProps.posts !== posts){
            this.handleData();
        } else if (indexPosts !== -1)
        {
            this.informationAlert();
            const log = posts.splice(indexPosts, 1);
            console.log(log);
        }   
    }
```

** When I added loop if (indexPosts !== -1)  then my array is cut only one object :-) 
API Posts: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/

The results are visible at this link when you press details and then the delete icon: https://scherlock90.github.io/api-post-task/

Comment: you should also not be mutating props like that. Create a piece of state that holds your mutated array.

Comment: Please post your sample array and what is in `deletedPost.`

Comment: @Chase 
why is this the wrong way to mutate data?

Comment: I added the first post probably the information you asked for. @kiranvj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to delete an element from array.
In splice you need to provide startIndex and number of elements to remove in second argument. In below code find index using `[findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) method, second argument is 1 as we need to remove only 1 element.

Try this

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevProps.deletedPost) {
            const { posts } = this.props
            const letang = posts.splice(posts.findIndex( (post)=> post.id === prevProps.deletedPost.id), 1);

           console.log(posts); // this should have array without deletedPost
        }
    }
```

Comment: Answers which explain the code they introduce are more useful than those which do not...

Comment: @kiranvj 
Your proposal results in an empty table, but no post is removed

Comment: @Sen console.log(posts); // this should have array without deletedPost

Comment: Yes I have, and there is empty array

Comment: But i change to 
 const letang = this.props.posts.slice(this.props.posts.findIndex( (post)=> post.id === this.state.postId), 1); then i see first posts in console log

Comment: @kiranvj when i click double then deleted post in array, but i changed on end for your code this.state.postId becuase i take id from the handleDeleted function I add this in EDIT 3

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.deletedPost) {
        const letang = this.props.posts;
        letang.splice(deletedPost, 1);
    }
}
```

the `slice()` takes the index of the object and an optional number of items to delete. since you just want to delete a single object you pass 1.

Comment: I tried a methody splice, but it still erases the first element from the array and not the selected one

Comment: is the `deletePost` an object or an `id`?

Answer (score 1):

This might help, try filtering out the object you dont want in the array.

```
componentDidUpdate (prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevProps.deletedPost) {
        const letang = this.props.items.filter(p => p.id !== prevProps.deletedPost.id);
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**
I think you should be deleting the items in your redux store rather than trying to delete the posts from your api since the api might rather be generating the same data randomly. Change your actionCreator to

```
export const deletedPost = (id) => {
   dispatch({
       type: DELETED_POST, 
       payload: id 
   });
};
```

Then use this in your reducer so you can focus on items array coming from your reducer store. Then remove `deletedPost: []` from your reducer.

```
...
    case DELETED_POST:
        const newItems = state.items.filter(p => p.id !== action.payload);
        return {
            ...state,
            items: [ ...newItems ],
        };
...
```

Comment: @SeN from your reducer, you are using items instead of posts, try replacing `this.props.posts.filter` with `this.props.items.filter`

Comment: but if you see EDIT 2 then you see why is posts

Comment: @SeN okay. now i see you are using `deletedPost2` in your `mapStateToProps`. change the `prevProps.deletedPost.id` to `prevProps.deletedPost2.id`

Comment: then i see error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at Posts.componentDidUpdate "

Comment: in console log I see a change in the sense of one post less always selected, but unfortunately it does not render the state in the displayed objects in the app. And it is always one element that disappears, not that the selected posts are subtracted one by one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194554/discussion-between-chukwuemeka-ihedoro-and-sen).

Answer (score 0):

use splice() to delete :), you can find the index of post which should be deleted and then delete it by using this method.